# Outlook rest api rich notification with multi/single value extended properties does not work

Tags: outlook-restapi

I just create an application to subscribe the Rich Notification by using MS Outlook Rest Api.
I can get the notification with value of the extended properties when I subscribe for the 'message' with extended properties like below:

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('user_id')/messages?$select=Id,Subject&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId
>   eq 'String {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8238' or
>   PropertyId eq 'Binary {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Id 0x3'
>   or PropertyId eq 'Binary {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id
>   0x23' or PropertyId eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
>   Id 0x8205')

But when I subscribe for the 'event' with the same resource's syntax as below:

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('user_id')/events?$select=Id,Subject&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId
>   eq 'String {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8238' or
>   PropertyId eq 'Binary {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Id 0x3'
>   or PropertyId eq 'Binary {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id
>   0x23' or PropertyId eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
>   Id 0x8205')

I only get the notification with the standard property like Id,Subject even though I can get these extended properties's value by Postman with the same resource's uri.